# Passing parameters of type object with PHPUnit's mocked object

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to pass an object when calling a mocked object. Like this:

```
public function testGetMedia()
{

$getPrimaryMediaHelper = $this->getMock('GetPrimaryMediaHelper', array('getMedia'));

$getPrimaryMediaHelper->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getMedia')
    ->with($media1, 'test');

}
```

The 1st parameter needs to be of type object, otherwise the test will fail. How can I mimic $media to be of type object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code should work

```
$getPrimaryMediaHelper->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getMedia')
    ->with($this->isType('object'));
```